# WorkflowApplication generate unhandle exception in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

am using simple persistence workflow application in ASP.NET when i try start workflow using 
WorkflowApplication invoker the .NET framework generate unhandled exception.

the exception is:

```
Type 'VacationRequestWorkflow.VacationRequestModel' in Assembly 'VacationRequestWorkflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84fad1a74027a4c8' is not marked as serializable.
```

i used

```
ActivityXamlServices.Load(
                ActivityXamlServices.CreateReader(
                    new XamlXmlReader("*XAML path*",
                        new XamlXmlReaderSettings { LocalAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() })));
```

to resolve this issue but didn't work.

please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this as simple as marking your class Serializable, using the [Serializable attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)?